# Read More Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to come up with a solution for adding read more functionality to a bunch of boxes on a page.

the simplest solution I saw was this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_read_more.asp but the issue is that the content is controlled by cms so adding in spans etc manually isn't an option. Additionally the JS on this example only activates on the first piece of content so is not suitable for multiple pieces of content.

I have been looking into creating some js that looks for the div class and adds the functionality in a certain amount of character numbers/words/based on div height but I am unable to find an appropriate solution so far. also ideally the read more button would not appear at all if the text is below the limit.

for reference here is a simplified version of what my html looks like:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="supp-item-body">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed dolor odio. Suspendisse tempor vestibulum sodales. Maecenas faucibus at libero vitae iaculis. Nam rhoncus sit amet lacus elementum elementum. Sed ut odio tristique, scelerisque odio a, lacinia risus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="supp-item-body">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed dolor odio. Suspendisse tempor vestibulum sodales. Maecenas faucibus at libero vitae iaculis. Nam rhoncus sit amet lacus elementum elementum. Sed ut odio tristique, scelerisque odio a, lacinia risus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="supp-item-body">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed dolor odio. Suspendisse tempor vestibulum sodales. Maecenas faucibus at libero vitae iaculis. Nam rhoncus sit amet lacus elementum elementum. Sed ut odio tristique, scelerisque odio a, lacinia risus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="supp-item-body">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed dolor odio. Suspendisse tempor vestibulum sodales. Maecenas faucibus at libero vitae iaculis. Nam rhoncus sit amet lacus elementum elementum. Sed ut odio tristique, scelerisque odio a, lacinia risus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

that plus a few more times over. I have removed non-relevant elements for clarity.

It may be that I am just looking in the wrong direction if so I am open to suggestions.

Many thanks.

Comment: The question is not quite clear, please explain it concisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that works great for the exact code you gave me, as long as each div has one paragraph with only plain text inside it. However, if you add HTML to the paragraphs (not just plain text), or if you want multiple paragraphs inside each `supp-item-body` div, then you'll have to adjust the code a bit. Note that this solution uses jQuery, which you added as a tag to your question, so I'm assuming you've already got it in your project.

Just copy and paste this into a blank .html file and open it in Chrome to see it in action.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="supp-item-body">
            <h3>title</h3>
            <p>Atheism includes any philosophy which claims that no God or gods exist, including any rational or reasoning creator of the universe. However, if premises begin to exist without reason, then conclusions drawn from them are also without reason. If there is no god, all initial human premises about the external world begin to exist without reason. Therefore, if there is no god, all human conclusions about the external world are also without reason.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="supp-item-body">
            <h3>title</h3>
            <p>Polytheism refers to any philosophy which claims that there are multiple supreme creators of the universe. However, if anyone is not the author of every aspect of creation, then his authority is insufficient to rationally guarantee the behavior of creation. Under polytheism, no one is the author of every aspect of creation. Therefore, under polytheism, no one has the authority to rationally guarantee the behavior of creation.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="supp-item-body">
            <h3>title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed dolor odio. Suspendisse tempor vestibulum sodales. Maecenas faucibus at libero vitae iaculis. Nam rhoncus sit amet lacus elementum elementum. Sed ut odio tristique, scelerisque odio a, lacinia risus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="supp-item-body">
            <h3>title</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed dolor odio. Suspendisse tempor vestibulum sodales. Maecenas faucibus at libero vitae iaculis. Nam rhoncus sit amet lacus elementum elementum. Sed ut odio tristique, scelerisque odio a, lacinia risus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.supp-item-body p').each(function(i, el)
        {
            var p = $(el);
            var pTxt = p.text();
            if (pTxt.length > 120)
            {
                var pTxtA = pTxt.substring(0, 120);
                pTxtA = pTxtA.substring(0, pTxtA.lastIndexOf(' '));
                pTxtB = pTxt.substring(pTxtA.length + 1);

                var pHtml = pTxtA + '<span class="dots">...</span> <span class="more-text" style="display: none;">' + pTxtB + '</span>';
                p.html(pHtml);
            }
            var btn = $('<button>Read more</button>')
            btn.unbind('click.more').bind('click.more', function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                p.find('.more-text').toggle();
                p.find('.dots').toggle();
            });
            p.after(btn);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is fantastic it works a treat! Thank you for your help and patience you have really helped me a lot. Yeah Jquery is fine the site I am working on uses a lot of it so it is not a problem. Thanks again!:-)